I wrote the code exactly like in the video, but it doesn't work. (tensorflow 2.10.0, python 3.10.11)
this neural network counts how many faringate degrees from degrees Celsius
================================================================
`import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
c = np.array([-40, -10, 0, 8, 15, 22, 38])
f = np.array([-40, 14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100])
model = keras.Sequential()                      
model.add(Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,), activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))
history = model.fit(c, f, epochs=500)
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.grid(True)
`plt.show()

=================================================================
the error is in this line:
history = model.fit(c, f, epochs=500)
`here is the part of my code where the terminal displayed the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "d:\Programming\Python\AI\With_tensorflow\One\Neyros\NeyroOptimization.py", line 25, in <module>
model.add(Dense(units=1, input=(1,), activation='linear'))`

so that the code does not give an error and works
google

Hi No need to share the good link. Your error is from your imports.

How about just C = 5/9 * (F-32)? Don’t really see the need for an NN here.

You need to include the error message itself in complete form, its not complete currently.

Your error is from your imports,
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense  #<- Corrected import
Even if you are using the import you mentioned above from the official link
Tensorflow_github_page it is meant to be this import below
from tensorflow.python.layers.core import Dense
See Tensorflow docs : Tensorflow
Here try this code
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense  # <- Correct import



c = np.array([-40, -10, 0, 8, 15, 22, 38])
f = np.array([-40, 14, 32, 46, 59, 72, 100])


model = keras.Sequential()                      
model.add(Dense(units=1, input_shape=(1,), activation='linear')) 


model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.1))

# Train the model
history = model.fit(c, f, epochs=500)

# Plot the loss
plt.plot(history.history['loss'])
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

